# Avoid Entering Password for key for each pod

Tags: terminal, cocoapods

I am trying to downloads pods for my Xcode project (there are many) and it is wanting me to enter my passphrase for almost every pod. How can I just enter my password once?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you generated `id_rsa` pair you have used a password. Now it can't be used without password. It is located in `~/.ssh` folder.

You can delete this key and recreate it.
But you lose all access to services where you use it.

Here is documentation how to create new pair (pub and priv keys)
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Also you can try to change password with `ssh-keygen -p`
https://serverfault.com/questions/50775/how-do-i-change-my-private-key-passphrase

When you use blank password, it will not prompt to you each time.